# get_the_author_meta( $field, 0 ) returns the administrator $field

Tags: author, user-meta

Just discovered that the `get_the_author_meta( 'birth_date', 0 )` returns the administrator birthdate. The same happens with other `$field` parameters for `$user_id = 0`. Is this an expected behavior for this function?

Comment: If the administrator is the author of the post, then yes, this would be expected. If the user ID is missing or false (which 0 is) then it defaults to the author of the current post.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly on the question - no, the `get_the_author_meta()` function is not supposed to return you by default the birthday date when you provide 0 for user ID, as it is not a default user meta field. Yet, providing 0 is the same as not providing a user ID at all, hence the function tries to get the author ID from the global `$authordata` variable.

Looking at the bottom of the code of the function, there is this last line in it, which suggests something (a plugin or the theme) might be messing with you:

```
    return apply_filters( "get_the_author_{$field}", $value, $user_id, $original_user_id );
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now! By the way, my question it is not strictly about the date of birth, but about any field/parameter.

Comment: @IurieMalai, I guess I misunderstood that you are receiving administrator's birth date no matter what field value you provide. You must be getting the case that Jacob suggested in his comment - doing the check on a post, published by the administrator.

Comment: The Jacob's comment and your answer both helped me to understand what happens. The part *"providing 0 is the same as not providing a user ID at all"* answered to my question.